# Unable to add library to Android Studio project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to add [this library](https://github.com/suchoX/PlacePicker/) to Android Studio *locally* using [this tutorial on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1MyBO9z7ojk).

However, I get errors that I can't post here because they're too many (99+).

Can someone tell me step by step (in detail) how to succesfully add this library to my project and be able to edit it afterwards?

This is the main error I get when I try to import this library: `Unable to determine constructor argument #1: missing parameter of type Factory, or no service of type Factory.

My build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.72"


        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-plugin:1.2'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.4'

        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: There is a large deprecation notice including the statement that the component will no longer work after 2019-01-29.

Comment: So you are asking how to add this library but you actually want to add a different library!?

Comment: Can you post at leas some of the errors you getting?

Comment: have you migrated your app to androidx?

Comment: @mirsaidoff yes.

Comment: it is saying that the library is deprecated. I guess, that is the cause. I have installed it in my project and experienced the same problem. AFAIK, some of the dependencies which were used in this lib has been deprecated or removed as well.

Comment: @mirsaidoff It's not deprecated, please read carefully

Comment: this is the main error I get when I try to import this library: `Unable to determine constructor argument #1: missing parameter of type Factory, or no service of type Factory<LoggingManagerInternal>.` @LevM.

Comment: Searching google for that error indicates is is caused by incompatible version of com.github.dcendents.android-maven plugin. Find it in you gradle file and try to update the version

Comment: @LevM. I still get the same error.

Comment: @Panjeet did you solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your step-by-step guide:

1. Create an empty project or open your existing project where you want to add this library.
2. Clone the library project from the git or download the zip and extract it in some other directory.
3. Now, in Android Studio, go to `File -> New -> Import Module...`. Select the cloned/extracted library directory. Make sure the `:placepicker` module is selected for import. Then click `Finish`.

[image]

4. Now copy two files `bintray.gradle` and `install.gradle` from cloned/extracted project root directory to your own project root directory. Add this point your project structure should look like this:

[image]

5. Now open your project level `build.gradle`. Add `ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.72'` inside `buildscript {` and also add following dependencies:

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.5'
classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.1'
```

Overall, this will look like:

[image]

6. Finally, go to `File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files`. It will take some time to download the missing dependencies and you have now successfully integrated the library within your project which is fully editable.
7. Now to make this library work in your own app module, in the `build.gradle` file of your app module, add this inside dependencies section:

`api project(':placepicker')`

Answer (score 0):

Step by step description:

1. Then ceck out the git project to your machine.
2. Modify and build it with a new Version.
3. Add the dipendency as Jar from Your local filesystem in Android Studio.

[image: dd]Try this:
<kbd>File</kbd> > <kbd>Project Structure</kbd> > <kbd>Dependencies Tab</kbd> > <kbd>Add module dependency</kbd> (`scope = compile`)

Where the module dependency is the project library Android folder.

Comment: Can you please give more details and steps from beginning to end? (for example: which folder from this GitHub library to add, what to do next etc.

Comment: instead of guava in the dependency manager write: com.sucho:placepicker:1.1.1 and > search

Comment: I searched for com.sucho:placepicker:1.1.1 and it didn't find it

Comment: the problem is that I want to be able to modify the library. I won't be able to modify it if I do `implementation 'com.sucho:placepicker:1.1.1'`

Comment: Then ceck out the git project. Modify and build it with a new Version and add the dipendency as Jar from Your local filesystem...

Comment: Please tell me how to do that step by step in your answer, thanks

Comment: Your answer is not clear enough unfortunately, I need detailed step by step as I'm a beginner

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I'll only award the bounty when the asker's problem has been fully resolved, so please do add more details

Comment: Could you post your gradle.build file contents?

Comment: have a look at this tutorial on how to create and deploy a android library.
Goto File -> New ->  Project From Version control and put this url: https://github.com/suchoX/PlacePicker.git then click Clone. You then do your modifications. In the tutorial look at how to publish your version. Then Import the new version you built to your project like described over. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Or edit your gradle.build like in the picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In build.gradle(Module.app) file add this.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:17.0.0'
```

let me knew if it's work.